# Problem with javascript in firefox when moving google ads

Tags: javascript, firefox, ads

i have a website with google ads on it. i would like to make it load faster. thus i moved all the google scripts to the bottom of the page. i also have a placeholder at the location where the ad(s) should be displayed and other divs that (initially) get the ads. finally (in window.onload) i'm moving the ads that have just be fetched from google to their target locations.

(a simple example page is here: http://www.nickles.de/temp/ads.html ) [forgot: it's only the text ads that don't show. when google delivers banners/graphics or suchlike, it works. thus, to see the code fail at the given url, you might need to reload the page several times...]

this works in ie, but it doesn't work in ff. (that is, in firefox, non-text ads show up fine, while text-ads don't. [or at least, not in a reliable way.])

any ideas what would be causing this?

Thanks! 
-thomas woelfer

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me in FF either, however when I disable the AdBlockPlus extension it does & I can see 2 banners.

(Its matching the filter "||googleadservices.com^$third-party")

Comment: well these ads come from the real ad-server: when google delivers "banners", they _are_ displayed in ff. you might need to reload several times until google starts to deliver text ads. these are the ones that are not visible in ff. (with or without addblock extensions).

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://www.nickles.de/temp/ads2.html) is a working version incase someone else needs stuff like that.